# Validate API Request with multiple related models in Laravel

Tags: laravel

so I have setup Laravel backend with VueJs frontend.
I have a model (Project) which hasMany related submodels (Plannings).

No I have a request, which returns the Project model with it's related Plannings.

**I'd like to validate, that the plannings are required, and each planning exists and belongs to this Project and the field 'planning_order' is required for each planning.**

How can I implement that in my UpdatePlanningOrderRequest?

So far I only have the following:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|exists:App\Models\Project,id',
            'plannings' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) that leverages Eloquent's [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), to verify that the given Id is related to a specific record.